# How to check if Sopcast Stream is online?

Tags: c#, vb.net

For now, I am using the SopCore control.
I initialize the player, I set the sopcast address (.SetSopAddress) and I play it.
After this, I check if the buffering started, if it did, the stream is online.

However, I want to do it in a faster way. There are any other alternatives?

Stream example: sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/149257

EDIT: Ok, I am having another problem. I was pretty sure I will be able to achieve this with the sopcore control, but it seems I was wrong. I cannot find out if the stream is online is offline there either.

Any solutions...?